# adding chart to worksheet in excel (vba) fails

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following very simple code which however fails

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim ShapeRef As Shape
Set ws = Sheets("DatenFilledChart") 
ShapeRef = ws.Shapes.AddChart()
```

with error 91: variable not defined.

I fail to understand why this fails.

Answer (score 1):

A `Shape` is an object so you need to use `Set` like you have done for the `Sheets` object.  Although this is a Run-time error '91' the error description should be 'Object variable or With block variable not set'.

Anyway, try setting the object like so: `Set ShapeRef = ws.Shapes.AddChart()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to add this chart as a member of shapes collection?

If not, if you need to work with the ChartObject, do this:

```
''Create a chart object (size/dimensions may be overridden or changed later in your code)
Set ShapeRef = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=chtLeft, Top:=chtTop, Width:=740, Height:=300)
```

If you need to work with the Chart, add another variable:

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ShapeRef.Chart
```